# Which Stack Exchange site is appropriate for asking for the best solution to make a website accessible for blind editors?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to make a small existing website (containing few pages only) editable, so the blind owner of the website can edit it herself.

Technologically, I'm not fixed to any approach: a CMS like Drupal or Wordpress or even completely different approaches are fine – as long as it is a good solution for the impaired editing person.

I'm interested in existing approaches, experiences, recommendations.
Since existing information on "backend accessibility" is thin and my question therefore is very broad, I don't know what's the best stack exchange site to post on; or maybe asking on multiple sites separately, with adjusted site-specific focus.

Comment: Are you looking more for what tool to use or for what to do with some tool?

Comment: As @bad_coder said: my question is very broad in this stage — I think I will do my first try in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com) can be a good place to ask about specific design choices. A [search for the keyword blind](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=blind) gives a significant number of results. Also their  [accessibility tag](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/40893) is synonimized with disability and some question are similar to your problem (e.g. I like [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/40893)).

Their Help Center [What topics can I ask about here?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) also seems to suggest your question could be acceptable there.

However, the way you are presenting the question here does seems to imply you are still in the early stages of prospecting for technologies. In that sense, as Ruben said, [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) is the right place to ask (e.g. [this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/14695) gives an interesting recommendation).

Overall, I think your question is still very broad. At this stage, the ideal would be an entire CMS system for users with a high degree of visual impairment. I don't know if such a system exists, or if the better approach is finding adequate tools for your friend to automate her content production and have someone collaborate in the publication process. (A divide-and-conquer strategy might be the most pragmatic approach.)

Comment: Your post has clarified a lot for me. I will give https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ a try. I like your pragmatic approach with by adopting a collaborative process for publication because of its social layer, but in the very case, I am looking for a solution where no other person is needed to publish.

Comment: @Madamadam I tried googling this for another perspective (I recommend you also google it). From what I understand the current state of UX for persons with visual impairment is focused on allowing them to read content, and to a lesser extent to produce content. This falls under specific [HMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface) but publishing it is necessarily a complex multi-step process and from my searches there isn't a readily available easy-to-use interface for that - and that is a shame.

Comment: @Madamadam even if it's just a summary of your research with alternatives and possibilities I'm sure the readers would appreciate the contribution. I think this is likely an expertise field we don't hear enough about. So please let us know.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a CMS recommendation [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) might be the right place.

There are several sites dedicated to specific CMS. It might be worthy to take  a look to them:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com (tags: [accessibility](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility))
- https://joomla.stackexchange.com
- https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/
- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ (tags: [accessibility](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility))
- ...

Also take a look to the complete list of technology sites on https://stackexchange.com/technology

Comment: Thanks! Since I've done some websites with Drupal, I will post a more specific question to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/